# Generating Java Pojos from JSON schema via json2pojo - Getting classes with same name but containing _

Tags: java, json, maven, pojo

I'm trying to generate JavaPojos from a JSON schema via the maven json2pojo plugin.
I've created a JSON schema with (jsonschema.net/#/): https://paste.ee/p/tRpCm from the JSON data (https://www.zerobin.net/?4b87daed0bfc3695#04kKki+hhzDkChcIUs1p/z5mRMOTWH9oXJguzbg43xg=) which I received through Simulationcraft (https://github.com/simulationcraft/simc). But json2pojo creates multiple classes with the same name with an additional "_".

[image: EclipseView]

I think the schema is not working but I don't know how to handle this issue.

Pom:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.jsonschema2pojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.4.27</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schema</sourceDirectory>
                    <targetPackage>com.example.types</targetPackage>
                    <annotationStyle>jackson2</annotationStyle>
                    <generateBuilders>true</generateBuilders>
                    <initializeCollections>true</initializeCollections>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you want to solve? I'm talking about the root requirement.

Comment: To avoid the generation of the classes with "_". These are all the same classes with more or less properties. And the root of the problem has to be in the json schema. So I want to finde a way to create a working json schema to generate non multiple java pojos. The json looks like this: [link](https://www.zerobin.net/?4b87daed0bfc3695#04kKki+hhzDkChcIUs1p/z5mRMOTWH9oXJguzbg43xg=)